# Spring Restful service - replace queryString with dynamic values

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to consume restful web service using RestTemplate class.

**Sample code:**

```
String quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/f27ec8db-af05-4f36-916e-3d57f91ecf5e?&fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups", String.class);
            log.info(quote.toString());
```

In this queryString i want to dynamically pass `f27ec8db-af05-4f36-916e-3d57f91ecf5e`. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any url variable can be wrapped in **{}** and passed in as a variable. If you have more than one it's replace them in order.

If you need a more complicated logic use [UriComponentsBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) to build your url.

```
String quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/{dynamic-param}?&fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups", String.class, "f27ec8db-af05-4f36-916e-3d57f91ecf5e");
```